# Boost Python, Visual studio does not create DLL

Tags: python, c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

So I finally managed to build my boost::python project without any errors in Visual Studio, just to find out that Visual Studio doesn't create a DLL for me. I use this example which is found in most of the tutorials (in some form):

```
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>


char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(myFirstModule)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

The output of Visual Studio reads:

```
1>  Finished generating code
1>  test.vcxproj -> P:\blub\x64\Release\test.dll
1>  test.vcxproj -> P:\blub\x64\Release\test.pdb (Full PDB)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So it looks fine, but no DLL in the folders mentioned.

Comment: Could you post the full build log? Another thing, is `P:\` a network drive?

Comment: Yes, P is a Network drive, and what you see is basically the build log. The only thing that I did not copy is, creating library and 2 of 573 functions were compiled, the rest were copied from previous compilation.

Comment: Ok, so it P is a network drive, that could be the problem. Are you sure to have the `write permission` for build destination folder? or that could be a problem with VS and network drives, also if i doubt that. If i were you i'd try to locate the build on a local drive just to see

Comment: Ok, that did it. So should I delete the question? Because the chances of anyone finding the answer to the title useful is I guess close to zero.

Comment: No you shouldn't. Even if that could help few people, it can always be useful. There are more and more network drives so it could happen. Let me put my comment into an answer later in thee day, and i guess you can accept it. Glad your problem is solved!

Comment: just a thing, when you said that did it? what was it exactly? a permissions problem or just because it was on a network drive?

Comment: I think it was a permission issue, as it worked on a different network drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Visual Studio **Output Window** log you provided, it seems that Visual Studio did its part of the job (at least says it did).

I guess, from the path `P:\blub\x64\Release\test.dll` starting with drive letter `P:\`, that the destination folder is located on a network share.

**You probably don't have the permission :**

- to **modify** this folder
- to **write** `test.dll`
- or both

Try to modify the destination path, to a folder you are sure you can write into, in the *Project Settings* and see if that solves your problem.

If you **have to** use a network share, [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx)